# How to add buttons in one column of pivotted AG Grid

Tags: angular, pivot, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I use ag grid in pivot mode:
https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/pivoting/
I want to have icon at the end of each row to click on it and open the dialog. something like this:
https://blog.ag-grid.com/cell-renderers-in-ag-grid-every-different-flavour/
But in pivot mode I can not add additional column, how can I do that?
my columns definition is:

```
colDef: ColDef[] = [
  {field: 'name', rowGroup: true, width: 250, resizable: true, flex: 3, suppressSizeToFit: false},
  {
    field: 'period',
    pivot: true,
    enablePivot: true,
    pivotComparator: ascYearComparator,
  },
  {
    field: 'hValue',
    aggFunc: 'last',
    flex: 1,
    maxWidth: 80,
    minWidth: 50,
    valueFormatter: UtilsService.percentandNegativeFormatter,
    cellStyle: params => {
      if (params.value < 0) {
        return {color: '#DE4A55'};
      } else {
        return {color: '#323E54', opacity: '0.5'};
      }
    },
  },
  {
    field: 'adjustedValue',
    aggFunc: 'last',
    flex: 2,
    minWidth: 150,
    valueFormatter: UtilsService.negativeFormatterSet,
    cellStyle: params => {
      if (params.value < 0) {
        return {color: '#F7525F'};
      } else {
        return {color: '#323E54'};
      }
    },
  },
];
```

any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

We can use auto group column for this purpose

Define a new component using cell renderer feature

btn-cell-renderer.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { ICellRendererParams } from 'ag-grid-community';

@Component({
  selector: 'btn-component',
  template: `
    <span>
      <span>{{ cellValue }}</span
      >&nbsp;
      <button (click)="buttonClicked()">Click me!</button>
    </span>
  `,
})
export class BtnCellRenderer implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  public cellValue!: string;

  // gets called once before the renderer is used
  agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
    this.cellValue = this.getValueToDisplay(params);
  }

  // gets called whenever the user gets the cell to refresh
  refresh(params: ICellRendererParams) {
    // set value into cell again
    this.cellValue = this.getValueToDisplay(params);
    return true;
  }

  buttonClicked() {
    alert(`${this.cellValue} was clicked`);
  }

  getValueToDisplay(params: ICellRendererParams) {
    return params.valueFormatted ? params.valueFormatted : params.value;
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BtnCellRenderer } from './btn-cell-renderer.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, AgGridModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, BtnCellRenderer],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Use it in your autoGroupColumnDef props

app.component.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ColDef, GridReadyEvent } from 'ag-grid-community';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
import { IOlympicData } from './interfaces';
import { BtnCellRenderer } from './btn-cell-renderer.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%;">
    <ag-grid-angular
      style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
      class="ag-theme-alpine"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
      [autoGroupColumnDef]="autoGroupColumnDef"
      [pivotMode]="true"
      [rowData]="rowData"
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
  </div> `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    { field: 'country', rowGroup: true, enableRowGroup: true },
    { field: 'sport', pivot: true },
    { field: 'year' },
    { field: 'date' },
    { field: 'gold', aggFunc: 'sum' },
    { field: 'silver', aggFunc: 'sum' },
    { field: 'bronze', aggFunc: 'sum' },
  ];
  public defaultColDef: ColDef = {
    flex: 1,
    minWidth: 150,
    sortable: true,
    resizable: true,
  };
  public autoGroupColumnDef: ColDef = {
    minWidth: 250,
    cellRenderer: BtnCellRenderer,
  };
  public rowData!: IOlympicData[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent<IOlympicData>) {
    this.http
      .get<IOlympicData[]>(
        'https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json'
      )
      .subscribe((data) => (this.rowData = data));
  }
}
```

Result

[image: Result]

Playground: https://plnkr.co/edit/mgrB3Fs6SYaykDcZ?preview

Read more on https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/

**UPDATE**

You want to include an additional column to show buttons while in pivot mode? I guess we cannot do that.

Let's check what the official documentation says about it

> **Pivot Mode**
>
> Pivot mode is required to be turned on for pivoting to work. When the
> grid is in pivot mode, the following will happen:
>
> - Only columns with Group, Pivot or Value active will be included in the grid.
> - Only aggregated rows will be shown, the lowest level rowData will not be displayed.

We have just one group row in this case and we cannot have an additional group row in pivot mode.

Please read on https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/pivoting/

Comment: It is very good idea, thank you very much Ahment, But I want to have buttons in a separate column not near to row group name.

Comment: I guess you cannot do that. I will explain why.